# Why does the column-type of the query change depending on its values?

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored function that calculates a price and returns it as a float:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[product_get_GrossPrice] (@pid INTEGER) 
RETURNS FLOAT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret AS FLOAT 

    SELECT
        @ret = (ROUND((price * (CAST(1 AS FLOAT) + (CAST(ISNULL(tax, 0) AS FLOAT) / CAST(100 AS FLOAT)))), 0))
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        id = @pid

    RETURN @ret
END
```

This function is used in a query like this:

```
SELECT
    p.*, dbo.product_get_GrossPrice(p.id) as gross_price
FROM 
    products
ORDER BY 
    id
```

On the web server the following code is used to read the column `gross_price`:

```
double? grossPrice = dataRow.Field<double?>("gross_price");
```

This works fine until the query returns only 0s and 1s in the column. It seems that if this is the case the column automatically turns into a boolean and the cast fails.

So what I did to solve this is that I changed the query to this:

```
select p.*, cast(dbo.product_get_GrossPrice(p.id) as float) as gross_price
from products
order by id
```

I've never encountered this problem before and it gives me a strange feeling in the stomach.

**Question:** what is going on here and do I have to cast every column to its desired data type to be sure that the casts won't break?

Comment: I suspect the problem(s) are in code you've not shown us - any particular query should always produce a result set with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their names and their *types*. Are you able to create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The only thing I removed for simplicity is that the query is stored as a view. Can that make a difference?

Comment: Please provide some sample data which shows this behavior.

Comment: @SteveFord: What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Okay, so not much missing *SQL* code. But there's certainly a fair chunk of code before we get to the point of having the variable `dataRow` assigned to something useful from the database. Don't *assume* that the problem is on the SQL side rather than the C# one.

Comment: So show us some sample data from the products table that demonstrates this behavior, show us what data your SELECT p.*, product_get_GrossPrice(p.id) as gross_price .... returns etc.

Comment: Run this query to check the type view columns: SELECT v.name, v.schema_id, c.name, c.column_id, c.system_type_id, t.name
FROM sys.views AS v
 INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON v.object_id = c.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
WHERE v.name = '[your view name]'

Comment: This is odd. The query of @Alex returned INT for the type of "gross_price" and this would explain the casting error. Then I did some changes/testing on the function `product_get_GrossPrice` to make it return specific values like 1, 0 or NULL and suddenly the type of the column changed to FLOAT and the error is gone. I can now remove the cast from the query. Maybe the problem was that the query is saved as a view and it was somehow cached incorrectly. I've seen that happen before. Thanks anyway guys!